# change a list while iterating or using a for each loop

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to iterate (or use a for each loop) on a Linked list class and be able to change the item (when found) to a passed in parameter.

```
for(Item n : items) 
{
    if (n.getKey().equals(key))
    {
         n = new Item(key, value);
    }
}
```

Does this change of data work or is it temporary (only to be lost when the activation record is deleted)?

Comment: Trying using a basic for loop `for (int i=0;i<n.size();n++)`

Comment: With lists there's no guarantee of linear time, an iterator guarantees that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate over a collection and modify it. You will always get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. First off all you need to use an iterator, to remove the item. Then you can use a second list to store the data you want to add.

Here you are an example:

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

        linkedList.add("This");
        linkedList.add("is");
        linkedList.add("an");
        linkedList.add("test");

        LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<String>();

        for (Iterator<String> iterator = linkedList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String string = (String) iterator.next();

            if(string.equals("an")) {
                iterator.remove();

                temp.add("a");
            }
        }

        linkedList.addAll(temp);
```

You can call `iterator.remove()` to savely remove the current item from list.

Comment: won't this throw an exception? or does the iterator die and the loop terminate?

Comment: There won't die anything and it works perfectly fine ;) - This will replace "an" for "a"

Comment: There is no guarantee that you'll get `ConcurrentModificationException`. From its JavaDocs "Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs."

Answer (score 0):

You are using fast enumeration, which protects the list that you are iterating through. If you would like to change the data in the list, you would need to use a traditional for loop.

Basically how fast enumeration works is it makes the array read-only in the block of code because you have no access to what integer the iteration is.

You could do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    if (n.getKey().equals(key))
    {
         items[i] = new Item(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: but the reason I don't want to use this is that I am using a Linked List class which cannot be accessed in constant time with the .get() or .replace() methods.

Comment: But couldn't you do item[i].getKey().equals(key))?

Comment: the items is a LinkedList object

Comment: @JakeChasan you should also explain how to use a traditional loop.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with code that will replace (thus save) the object into the array. Does this not work in your specific situation?

Comment: this is an array implementation, items is a LinkedList

Comment: Generally, i would discourage any random access on anything declared as List<> instance.  Random access on an arbitrary List has O(N) execution time, which means your above loop can actually have O(N^2) execution time to iterate.  However, the Iterator instances returned from all the collection classes are highly optimized, and using the Iterator should always yield O(N) execution time.  In reality for ArrayList you get O(N) using random access and LinkedList gives you O(N^2).  So if you're not sure that you're using ArrayList, stay away from the above.